# Expected type 'Iterable' (matched generic type 'Iterable[_T1]'), got 'RasterImageExtensions' instead

Tags: python

**Python 3.8**

**Pycharm Community 2020.3**

```
class RasterImageExtensions(Enum):
    WEBP = 'webp'
    PNG = 'png'
    JPG = 'jpg'
    TIFF = 'tif'


permitted_extensions = list(map(lambda item: item.name.lower(), RasterImageExtensions))
```

permitted_ext_type equals to RasterImageExtensions here.

Pycharm gives me a warning:

> Expected type 'Iterable' (matched generic type 'Iterable[_T1]'), got
> 'RasterImageExtensions' instead

Could you tell me how to correct it? I don't like warnings.

Comment: Could you please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Pardon. I have changed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because **`map`** takes an `iterable` as a second positional argument, and you passed a class instead.

I'm assuming you're trying to pass the list of variables defined within that class, so you may want to use **`vars()`**:

```
permitted_extensions = list(map(lambda item: item.name.lower(), vars(RasterImageExtensions)))
```

Comment: What is `vars`?

Comment: @Gulzar (from a search's query of "python vars"): https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_vars.asp

Comment: @RiccardoVolpe answers should be self-contained even if easily obtainable.